# The table (xxxxx) cannot be the child table to itself in nested relations

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing

Recently I am dealing with parsing xml using vb.net.

As I get more deeply, I understand that there are 2 types of contents of the xml files. The first type are xmls that I can convert easily into a dataset and I can easily see their content structure using VS dataset visualizer and the 2nd are xmls that contain the same nodes multiple times and I get The table (xxxxx) cannot be the child table to itself in nested relations.

For example I have the following xml that is a query execution plan from SQL Server and I get an error

> The table (ScalarOperator) cannot be the child table to itself in nested relations

I want to get from the XML some specific info for example the output columns which are in the `ColumnReference`" node.

I have this code in which I download the xml plan in a local file and I am trying to parse it.

The error hits on the last line of code

```
    Dim v4str As String = _Session.ExecuteSQLScalar(execplan, v4SQLParams)
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("exectmpplan.xml", True)
    file.WriteLine(v4str)
    file.Close()

    Dim exectmpplan As New XmlDocument()
    exectmpplan.Load("exectmpplan.xml")
    Dim xmlnoerdr As New XmlNodeReader(exectmpplan)

    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    ds.ReadXml(xmlnoerdr)
```

The xml is :

```
<ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" Version="1.539" Build="15.0.2080.9">
    <BatchSequence>
        <Batch>
           <Statements>
               <StmtSimple StatementText="SELECT A.ItemGID,A.Code,A.fCompanyCode, A.fColorCode, A.fSizeCode, B.KindSite, B.KindWH, B.gid as SiteGid , C.Description from ESMMItemCodes a CROSS JOIN (SELECT GID,KindSite,KindWH FROM ESGOSites where fPersonCodeGID IN (SELECT top 1 fPersonCodeGID FROM ESGOCompany  ) AND KindSite=1 UNION ALL  SELECT GID,KindSite,KindWH FROM ESGOSites where fSiteGID IN (SELECT GID from ESGOSites WHERE fpersonCodeGid in (SELECT top 1 fPersonCodeGID FROM ESGOCompany ) AND KindSite=1)) b LEFT OUTER JOIN ESGOSites c on b.GID=c.GID WHERE a.NumericField1=0" StatementId="1" StatementCompId="1" StatementType="SELECT" RetrievedFromCache="true" StatementSubTreeCost="0.110352" StatementEstRows="2927.62" SecurityPolicyApplied="false" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" QueryHash="0x155DC656E56E98CB" QueryPlanHash="0x3EF126EF26FDB4FD" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70"><StatementSetOptions QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" /><QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="88" CompileTime="25" CompileCPU="25" CompileMemory="2072"><MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="512" SerialDesiredMemory="544" GrantedMemory="0" MaxUsedMemory="0" /><OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="99692" EstimatedPagesCached="49846" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="4" MaxCompileMemory="649288" /><RelOp NodeId="0" PhysicalOp="Merge Join" LogicalOp="Right Outer Join" EstimateRows="2927.62" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="0.0124106" AvgRowSize="249" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.110352" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="ItemGID" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="Code" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="fCompanyCode" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="fColorCode" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="fSizeCode" /><ColumnReference Column="Union1011" /><ColumnReference Column="Union1012" /><ColumnReference Column="Union1013" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Alias="[c]" Column="Description" /></OutputList><Merge ManyToMany="0"><InnerSideJoinColumns><ColumnReference Column="Union1011" /></InnerSideJoinColumns><OuterSideJoinColumns><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Alias="[c]" Column="GID" /></OuterSideJoinColumns><Residual><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Union1011]=[ESERPDEMOV4].[dbo].[ESGOSites].[GID] as [c].[GID]"><Compare CompareOp="EQ"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="Union1011" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Alias="[c]" Column="GID" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Residual><RelOp NodeId="1" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimateRows="174" EstimatedRowsRead="174" EstimateIO="0.020162" EstimateCPU="0.0003484" AvgRowSize="127" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0205104" TableCardinality="174" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Alias="[c]" Column="GID" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Alias="[c]" Column="Description" /></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="1" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="0" ForceSeek="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0" Storage="RowStore"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Alias="[c]" Column="GID" /></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Alias="[c]" Column="Description" /></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Index="[PK_ESGOSites]" Alias="[c]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" /></IndexScan></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="2" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" LogicalOp="Inner Join" EstimateRows="2927.62" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="0.0122374" AvgRowSize="146" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.077428" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="ItemGID" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="Code" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="fCompanyCode" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="fColorCode" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="fSizeCode" /><ColumnReference Column="Union1011" /><ColumnReference Column="Union1012" /><ColumnReference Column="Union1013" /></OutputList><Warnings NoJoinPredicate="1" /><NestedLoops Optimized="0"><RelOp NodeId="3" PhysicalOp="Sort" LogicalOp="Sort" EstimateRows="3.06878" EstimateIO="0.0112613" EstimateCPU="0.000107769" AvgRowSize="25" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0378612" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Column="Union1011" /><ColumnReference Column="Union1012" /><ColumnReference Column="Union1013" /></OutputList><MemoryFractions Input="1" Output="1" /><Sort Distinct="0"><OrderBy><OrderByColumn Ascending="1"><ColumnReference Column="Union1011" /></OrderByColumn></OrderBy><RelOp NodeId="4" PhysicalOp="Concatenation" LogicalOp="Concatenation" EstimateRows="3.06878" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="3.06878e-07" AvgRowSize="25" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0264922" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Column="Union1011" /><ColumnReference Column="Union1012" /><ColumnReference Column="Union1013" /></OutputList><Concat><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Column="Union1011" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Column="Union1012" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindSite" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindSite" /></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Column="Union1013" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindWH" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindWH" /></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><RelOp NodeId="6" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" LogicalOp="Inner Join" EstimateRows="1.15079" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="4.81032e-06" AvgRowSize="25" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0100047" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindSite" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindWH" /></OutputList><NestedLoops Optimized="0"><OuterReferences><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></OuterReferences><RelOp NodeId="7" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" LogicalOp="Inner Join" EstimateRows="1.15079" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="4.81032e-06" AvgRowSize="23" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00657128" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></OutputList><NestedLoops Optimized="0"><OuterReferences><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOCompany]" Column="fPersonCodeGID" /></OuterReferences><RelOp NodeId="8" PhysicalOp="Top" LogicalOp="Top" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="1e-07" AvgRowSize="23" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032832" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOCompany]" Column="fPersonCodeGID" /></OutputList><Top RowCount="0" IsPercent="0" WithTies="0"><TopExpression><ScalarOperator ScalarString="(1)"><Const ConstValue="(1)" /></ScalarOperator></TopExpression><RelOp NodeId="9" PhysicalOp="Index Scan" LogicalOp="Index Scan" EstimateRows="1" EstimateRowsWithoutRowGoal="3" EstimatedRowsRead="3" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateCPU="0.0001603" AvgRowSize="23" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="3" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOCompany]" Column="fPersonCodeGID" /></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="0" ForcedIndex="0" ForceSeek="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0" Storage="RowStore"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOCompany]" Column="fPersonCodeGID" /></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOCompany]" Index="[IX_ESGOCompany_fPersonCodeGID]" TableReferenceId="1" IndexKind="NonClustered" Storage="RowStore" /></IndexScan></RelOp></Top></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="10" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" LogicalOp="Index Seek" EstimateRows="1.15079" EstimatedRowsRead="1.15079" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateCPU="0.000158266" AvgRowSize="23" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00328327" TableCardinality="174" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="1" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="0" ForceSeek="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0" Storage="RowStore"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Index="[IX_ESGOSites_ESPERF01]" TableReferenceId="1" IndexKind="NonClustered" Storage="RowStore" /><SeekPredicates><SeekPredicateNew><SeekKeys><Prefix ScanType="EQ"><RangeColumns><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="fPersonCodeGID" /></RangeColumns><RangeExpressions><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[ESERPDEMOV4].[dbo].[ESGOCompany].[fPersonCodeGID]"><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOCompany]" Column="fPersonCodeGID" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></RangeExpressions></Prefix></SeekKeys></SeekPredicateNew></SeekPredicates></IndexScan></RelOp></NestedLoops></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="12" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimateRows="1.15079" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" AvgRowSize="9" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00342859" TableCardinality="174" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0.150794" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindSite" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindWH" /></OutputList><IndexScan Lookup="1" Ordered="1" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="0" ForceSeek="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0" Storage="RowStore"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindSite" /></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindWH" /></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Index="[PK_ESGOSites]" TableReferenceId="-1" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" /><SeekPredicates><SeekPredicateNew><SeekKeys><Prefix ScanType="EQ"><RangeColumns><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></RangeColumns><RangeExpressions><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[ESERPDEMOV4].[dbo].[ESGOSites].[GID]"><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></RangeExpressions></Prefix></SeekKeys></SeekPredicateNew></SeekPredicates><Predicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[ESERPDEMOV4].[dbo].[ESGOSites].[KindSite]=(1)"><Compare CompareOp="EQ"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindSite" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="(1)" /></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Predicate></IndexScan></RelOp></NestedLoops></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="15" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" LogicalOp="Inner Join" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="4.18e-06" AvgRowSize="25" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0164867" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindSite" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindWH" /></OutputList><NestedLoops Optimized="0"><OuterReferences><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></OuterReferences><RelOp NodeId="16" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" LogicalOp="Inner Join" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="8.0172e-06" AvgRowSize="23" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0131994" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></OutputList><NestedLoops Optimized="0"><OuterReferences><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></OuterReferences><RelOp NodeId="17" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" LogicalOp="Inner Join" EstimateRows="1.15079" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="4.81032e-06" AvgRowSize="24" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00988303" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></OutputList><NestedLoops Optimized="0"><OuterReferences><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></OuterReferences><RelOp NodeId="18" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" LogicalOp="Inner Join" EstimateRows="1.15079" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="4.81032e-06" AvgRowSize="23" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00657128" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></OutputList><NestedLoops Optimized="0"><OuterReferences><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOCompany]" Column="fPersonCodeGID" /></OuterReferences><RelOp NodeId="19" PhysicalOp="Top" LogicalOp="Top" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="1e-07" AvgRowSize="23" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032832" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOCompany]" Column="fPersonCodeGID" /></OutputList><Top RowCount="0" IsPercent="0" WithTies="0"><TopExpression><ScalarOperator ScalarString="(1)"><Const ConstValue="(1)" /></ScalarOperator></TopExpression><RelOp NodeId="20" PhysicalOp="Index Scan" LogicalOp="Index Scan" EstimateRows="1" EstimateRowsWithoutRowGoal="3" EstimatedRowsRead="3" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateCPU="0.0001603" AvgRowSize="23" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="3" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOCompany]" Column="fPersonCodeGID" /></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="0" ForcedIndex="0" ForceSeek="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0" Storage="RowStore"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOCompany]" Column="fPersonCodeGID" /></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOCompany]" Index="[IX_ESGOCompany_fPersonCodeGID]" TableReferenceId="2" IndexKind="NonClustered" Storage="RowStore" /></IndexScan></RelOp></Top></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="21" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" LogicalOp="Index Seek" EstimateRows="1.15079" EstimatedRowsRead="1.15079" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateCPU="0.000158266" AvgRowSize="23" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00328327" TableCardinality="174" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="1" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="0" ForceSeek="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0" Storage="RowStore"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Index="[IX_ESGOSites_ESPERF01]" TableReferenceId="3" IndexKind="NonClustered" Storage="RowStore" /><SeekPredicates><SeekPredicateNew><SeekKeys><Prefix ScanType="EQ"><RangeColumns><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="fPersonCodeGID" /></RangeColumns><RangeExpressions><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[ESERPDEMOV4].[dbo].[ESGOCompany].[fPersonCodeGID]"><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOCompany]" Column="fPersonCodeGID" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></RangeExpressions></Prefix></SeekKeys></SeekPredicateNew></SeekPredicates></IndexScan></RelOp></NestedLoops></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="23" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimateRows="1.15079" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" AvgRowSize="9" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00330694" TableCardinality="174" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0.150794" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList /><IndexScan Lookup="1" Ordered="1" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="0" ForceSeek="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0" Storage="RowStore"><DefinedValues /><Object Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Index="[PK_ESGOSites]" TableReferenceId="-1" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" /><SeekPredicates><SeekPredicateNew><SeekKeys><Prefix ScanType="EQ"><RangeColumns><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></RangeColumns><RangeExpressions><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[ESERPDEMOV4].[dbo].[ESGOSites].[GID]"><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></RangeExpressions></Prefix></SeekKeys></SeekPredicateNew></SeekPredicates><Predicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[ESERPDEMOV4].[dbo].[ESGOSites].[KindSite]=(1)"><Compare CompareOp="EQ"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindSite" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="(1)" /></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Predicate></IndexScan></RelOp></NestedLoops></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="24" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" LogicalOp="Index Seek" EstimateRows="1.66667" EstimatedRowsRead="1.66667" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateCPU="0.000158833" AvgRowSize="23" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00330778" TableCardinality="174" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0.150794" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="1" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="0" ForceSeek="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0" Storage="RowStore"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Index="[IX_ESGOSites_fSiteGID]" TableReferenceId="2" IndexKind="NonClustered" Storage="RowStore" /><SeekPredicates><SeekPredicateNew><SeekKeys><Prefix ScanType="EQ"><RangeColumns><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="fSiteGID" /></RangeColumns><RangeExpressions><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[ESERPDEMOV4].[dbo].[ESGOSites].[GID]"><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></RangeExpressions></Prefix></SeekKeys></SeekPredicateNew></SeekPredicates></IndexScan></RelOp></NestedLoops></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="26" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" AvgRowSize="9" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="174" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindSite" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindWH" /></OutputList><IndexScan Lookup="1" Ordered="1" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="0" ForceSeek="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0" Storage="RowStore"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindSite" /></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="KindWH" /></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Index="[PK_ESGOSites]" TableReferenceId="-1" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" /><SeekPredicates><SeekPredicateNew><SeekKeys><Prefix ScanType="EQ"><RangeColumns><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></RangeColumns><RangeExpressions><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[ESERPDEMOV4].[dbo].[ESGOSites].[GID]"><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESGOSites]" Column="GID" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></RangeExpressions></Prefix></SeekKeys></SeekPredicateNew></SeekPredicates></IndexScan></RelOp></NestedLoops></RelOp></Concat></RelOp></Sort></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="27" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimateRows="954" EstimatedRowsRead="954" EstimateIO="0.0224628" EstimateCPU="0.0011279" AvgRowSize="141" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.025924" TableCardinality="954" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="2.06878" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="ItemGID" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="Code" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="fCompanyCode" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="fColorCode" /><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="fSizeCode" /></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="0" ForcedIndex="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0" Storage="RowStore"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="ItemGID" /></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="Code" /></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="fCompanyCode" /></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="fColorCode" /></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="fSizeCode" /></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Index="[PK_ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" /><Predicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[ESERPDEMOV4].[dbo].[ESMMItemCodes].[NumericField1] as [a].[NumericField1]=(0.0000000000)"><Compare CompareOp="EQ"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[ESERPDEMOV4]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[ESMMItemCodes]" Alias="[a]" Column="NumericField1" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="(0.0000000000)" /></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Predicate></IndexScan></RelOp></NestedLoops></RelOp></Merge></RelOp></QueryPlan></StmtSimple></Statements></Batch></BatchSequence></ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: DataSet cannot be used on an xml that is more than four levels or tags.  The results is useless.  The data becomes fragmented so data is useless.  You xml is not valid since each tag is not closed.

Comment: What do you mean is not valid ? This is xml is produced by sql and is 100% valid based on https://www.xmlvalidation.com . Are there any other methods suggested for the specific problem ?

Comment: What does `ExecuteSQLScalar` return?

Comment: A valid xml must have a closing tag for each open tag.

Comment: @jdweng if you scroll right and get the whole xml you will see that every tag is clossing

Comment: @mary executeSqlScalar is used for sql statements that return one row and only one column

Comment: Yes, but what does it return? What .NET datatype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found schema location on first line of the xml (http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan/sql2019/showplanxml.xsd) and then used the xsd.exe tool to create classes.  Then used code below to parse the xml

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Public Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME)
        Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(ShowPlanXML))
        Dim showPlanXml As ShowPlanXML = serializer.Deserialize(reader)

    End Sub
```